LinkedIn API, retrieve profile Information
How to with the linkedin API, after the user login in linkedin account the API retrieve all the profile information like Education, past jobs, certifications etc.
I'm aware that previous methods like "r_fullprofile" are now closed, what is the alternative to get a linkedin member information.
I already sign up in linkedin developer portal and the only information that it seems to be possible to get is just the UserName and Email.
